# Machine Learning Data Sets searchable by statistical properties

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

There are a number of collections of open example data sets for machine learning, e.g., the one of the [UC Irvine](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/). However, they are usually organized by source or topic. Does anyone know of a list or search engine for this kind of data set, which is organized by statistical properties like number of rows/columns, scale level of target variable, rare events data, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

The UCI Machine Learning Repository that you linked actually has datasets categorized by "Default Task", "Attribute Type", and "Data Type".

[image]

For this same repository, I'd use a search engine to search the text descriptions of each dataset. For example:

**https://encrypted.google.com/#q=outlier+site:archive.ics.uci.edu**

If you categorizied datasets systematically, I'm sure the community would be greatly appreciative if you shared the results!

---

Another option is to use a programming-language specific dataset package. R's "[datasets](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html)" comes to mind. Using R you can get summary information for all datasets by looping over each. More info:

```
library(help = "datasets")
```